# applying a function to each element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, std

I am writing a c++ program that reads in a list of doubles from a text file and stores them in an array.  I would like to apply a function to each double in the array one by one and test the result.  what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is "best"? You could achieve this using a simple for loop...

Comment: What do you mean by "test" the result?

Comment: thanks, just wanted to make sure i was working in the right direction

Answer (score 5):

That depends, if you want to store the results of the calls for later
and also require the original values, use `std::transform`. If you
only want to find out if all of the applications return true use
`std::all_of`, if you function is mutating use `std::for_each`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
std::vector<double> v;

// populate v

for (auto d : v) { auto res = do_something_with(d); verify(res); }
```